# Windows Phone 8.1 Exception when creating WriteableBiitmap

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a Windows Phone 8.1 app (Windows Runtime, not Silverlight 8.1), and I need to create a WriteableBitmap from a Stream, but when I try to do so, I get this exception: "An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

> Additional information: The component cannot be found. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x88982F50)"

I have tried a lot of things, but still no luck. My code is as follows:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var files = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.GetFilesAsync();
    for(int i=0; i<files.Count; i++)
    {
        var fileStream = await files[i].OpenReadAsync();
        if(fileStream != null)
        {
             WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromStream(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't happen if I replace

```
var fileStream = await files[i].OpenReadAsync();
```

with, for example,

```
var fileStream = await files[0].OpenReadAsync();
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd. I take it you have checked the "Pictures Library" capability in your appxmanifest file.

This code works for me:

```
public static async Task<WriteableBitmap> GetWritableBitmapFromStream(Stream stream)
{
    var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
    var pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, new BitmapTransform(), ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
    var pixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
    using (var bmpStream = bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
    {
        bmpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await bmpStream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, (int)bmpStream.Length);
    }
    return bmp;
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var files = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        // need "using System.IO" for this extension method
        using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = await GetWritableBitmapFromStream(fileStream);
            // do something with writableBmp
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I did: New empty WP 8.1 project; added a button to MainPage; added this code to code-behind; took some "photos" in the emulator; run the app. No issues. I don't know what else I can do. What exact line of code is throwing the error for you?

Comment: The line which is throwing the error is this: WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = await GetWriteableBitmapFromStream(fileStream);        But this only happens if I have more than 150 photos on the emulator, otherwise it works as expected.

Comment: What type of file is failing to be opened? Is it not a .jpg or .png file? Maybe the device has run out of memory by the 150th photo?

Comment: Yes, it throws me an OutOfMemoryException by the 150th photo. How can I do to solve it? I have already tried doing writeableBmp = null; GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect(); and with GC.ADDMemoryPressure(), with no luck. What else can I do?

Comment: Did you add any additional code? Did you reference the bitmap elsewhere? The bitmap won't be garbage collected if something (anything) is referencing it. You should run the memory profiler.

Comment: No, I simply added:                                                    var basicProperties = await files[i].GetBasicPropertiesAsync();    long size = (long)basicProperties.Size;                            writeableBmp = null;                                          GC.AddMemoryPressure(size);                                  GC.Collect();                                                  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();                              GC.Collect();                                                GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(size);